# completeness of rational numbers under discrete metric.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Is the set of all rational numbers is complete with respect to discrete metric? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

What is a Cauchy sequence for the discrete metric?

Comment: sequence with constant tail.

Comment: So it trivially converges to its tail.